# Saving a QGIS Project - Bad Layers?

Tags: qgis

this is a pretty noob question but how do you save a project without losing the layers? I was doing a hillshade analysis and saved the file as .qgz but only loads the .tif file. There is a dialog box that pops up and says "bad layers."

Using:

Macbook Air Sierra
Python 3.6
QGIS MacOS 3.2

How can I save the project when I'm not done yet?

Answer (score 3):

Some processing algorithms save the result in **temporary** files.

If you save the project and reopen it later, you get the `bad layer` dialogue because the temporary files are lost.

So save the **layers** to a permanent file format (such as shapefile or Geotiff) and location before closing the project to regain them later.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of layers are you using ?

If you're talking about **web** layers (wms, wfs ...) you have maybe lost connection with the server providing these layers.
If you're using **local** layers you maybe know that layers paths can be stored using *"absolute"* or *"relative"* paths (relative to the project) if you're using relative paths you must keep project and layers grouped (using subfolders if necessary) or qgis will prompt you to input the right files locations (in case any change occur in the tree structure) ...